# Optimal proposal for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm using Tierney's theorem

Tags: optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, measure-theory, lagrange-multipliers

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$c:=\lambda p\in(0,\infty)$$ and $$\mu:=\underbrace{\frac1cp}_{=:\:\tilde p}\lambda$$
- $q:E^2\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E^{\otimes2}$-measurable with $$\lambda q(x,\;\cdot\;)=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E$$ and $$Q(x,\;\cdot\;):=q(x,\;\cdot\;)\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E$$
- $$\alpha(x,y):=\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle1\wedge\frac{p(y)q(y,x)}{p(x)q(x,y)}&\text{, if }p(x)q(x,y)\ne0\\1&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E$$ and $$k(x,y):=\alpha(x,y)q(x,y)=\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle q(x,y)\wedge\frac{p(y)q(y,x)}{p(x)}&\text{, if }p(x)\ne0\\q(x,y)&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E$$
- $f\in L^2(\mu)$

> If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is the Markov chain generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal $Q$ and target $\mu$ and we want to minimize the asymptotic variance of $$A_n:=\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N,$$ [Tierney's theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1027961031) (a generalization of Peskun's theorem) tells us that we can equivalently maximize the quantity $$\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int\lambda({\rm d}y)k(x,y)|f(x)-f(y)|^2\tag1.$$ How is one usually solving this optimization problem (analytically)? Maybe using [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)?

Note that $$p(x)k(x,y)=p(x)q(x,y)\wedge p(y)q(y,x)=p(y)k(y,x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E\tag2.$$ Moreover, using $2(a\wedge b)=a+b-|a-b|$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$, we may write $$p(x)k(x,y)=\frac{p(x)q(x,y)+p(y)q(y,x)-|p(x)q(x,y)-p(y)q(y,x)|}2\tag3$$ With $(3)$ we can rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int Q(x,{\rm d}y)|f(x)-f(y)|^2\\&\;\;\;\;-\frac1{2c}\lambda({\rm d}x)\int\lambda({\rm d}y)|p(x)q(x,y)-p(y)q(y,x)||f(x)-f(y)|^2.
\end{split}\tag4
\end{equation}

While I don't know how useful this is, let me finally note that $$\frac1{2c}\lambda({\rm d}x)\int\lambda({\rm d}y)|p(x)q(x,y)-p(y)q(y,x)|=\left\|\mu\otimes Q-\lambda\otimes\overleftarrow Q_\mu\right\|\tag5,$$ where $\otimes$ denotes the [kernel product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Product_of_kernels) and $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Product_of_kernels) and $$\overleftarrow Q_\mu(y,\;\cdot\;):=q(\;\cdot\;,y)\mu.$$

> *Remark*: The particular instance of the problem I'm trying to solve is this one: [Variance reduction of an estimator arising from the marginal destribution of a Metropolis-Hastings chain](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/422838/222528).

Comment: Just as a comment about your questions overall - your questions have a huge amount of cruft associated with them, all the "Let ... be a measure space..." that adds nothing and undoubtedly dissuades a lot of people from reading further.  Your entire question is essentially contained in the first yellow box, you hardly need anything beyond that other than some brief, text-based, definitions of terms.  Your notation is more opaque than the Tierney paper... and this is common across all your questions.   This may explain why 7 of your 9 previous questions don't have a single answer...

Comment: I hope you take this in the helpful spirit which it's intended, I find your questions generally interesting myself.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you for your feedback. I guess you're right when you write that all the definitions dissuade a lot of people from reading further. And you're right when you write that the question is essentially contained in the first yellow box (that's why I highlighted it). However, since I basically want to know how we would solve the optimization problem for the quantity $(1)$ (including necessary constraints), I see no other way than giving all the necessary definitions.

Comment: @jbowman And what you wrote about Tierney's paper: It's an implication of Tierney's theorem that we may equivalently maximize $(1)$ if we want to minimize the asymptotic variance of $(A_n)_{\in\mathbb N}$. This is not stated in the paper, since the theorem is about an ordering of transition kernels of time-homogeneous Markov chains in general (not for the subclass of those arising from the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm).

Comment: This question hasn’t been answered in the generality you’re looking for. If it had been, tuning MH algorithms wouldn’t be a thing people have to do, but it is. There are rules of thumb for how to choose $q$, but they usually make more assumptions (e.g if $q$ is a random walk, how do we select the variance)

Comment: @Taylor Thank you very much for your comment. (a) What do you say to the particular situation described here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/422838/222528? (b) I thought we could use that the total variation distance is bounded by the Kullback-Leibler divergence and maybe it's possible to find the optimal choice for the quantity which arises from that. The solution wouldn't be a minimizer of the asymptotic variance, but it would be an upper bound. (Again, I'm primarily interested in the situation of the othr question.)

Comment: @Taylor To be precise: We may use that $$\left\|\mu\otimes Q-\lambda\otimes\overleftarrow Q_\mu\right\|\le\frac12 H\left(\mu\otimes Q\mid\lambda\otimes\overleftarrow Q_\mu\right)=\frac12\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int Q(x,{\rm d}y)\ln\frac{p(x)q(x,y)}{p(y)q(y,x)}\tag6$$ (and an analogue result holds in the other question).

Comment: @Taylor If I apply the same idea to the bound we obtain in terms of the $\chi^2$-divergence, I end up with this optimization problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3338883/47771. We should be able to solve this by the usual Lagrange multiplier method.